# PHP returns 500 error when having too many $_POST variables

Tags: php, vps, ini

I have a php page in my vps which expects 46 $_POST variables.
Whenever I try to address it, it returns a 500 Internal Server Error response.
When I delete 8+ $_POST variables from the file, everything works as expected.
I have alraedy tried setting the `max_input_vars` to `3000` in the `php.ini` (and restarting the server afterwards). 
I have also tried changing the `.htaccess` file, nothing worked. 
Any suggestions ? 
Thanks in advance.

Edit : 
The error log :

```
[Fri Dec 23 17:51:22.902648 2016] [:error] [pid 27211] [client 77.138.82.103:54270] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$Phase_3_Q_Before' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/server/addSwitch.php on line 43
[Fri Dec 23 17:51:24.215003 2016] [:error] [pid 27212] [client 77.138.82.103:54271] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$Phase_3_Q_Before' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/server/addSwitch.php on line 43
[Fri Dec 23 17:51:25.806288 2016] [:error] [pid 27213] [client 77.138.82.103:54280] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$Phase_3_Q_Before' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/server/addSwitch.php on line 43
[Fri Dec 23 17:51:27.587422 2016] [:error] [pid 27210] [client 77.138.82.103:54302] PHP Warning:  phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /var/www/html/info.php on line 2
[Fri Dec 23 17:51:34.500954 2016] [:error] [pid 27212] [client 77.138.82.103:54350] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$Phase_3_Q_Before' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/server/addSwitch.php on line 43
[Fri Dec 23 17:51:39.513983 2016] [:error] [pid 27260] [client 77.138.82.103:54351] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$Phase_3_Q_Before' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/server/addSwitch.php on line 43
```

Part of the code :

```
$Phase_3_U_Before = $_POST['Phase_3_U_Before'];
$Phase_3_I_Before = $_POST['Phase_3_I_Before'];
$Phase_3_P_Before = $_POST['Phase_3_P_Before'];
$Phase_3_S_Before = $_POST['Phase_3_S_Before'];
$Phase_3_Q_Before = $_POST['Phase_3_Q_Before'];
$Phase_3_cos_Before = $_POST['Phase_3_cos_Before'];
$Phase_3_U_After = $_POST['Phase_3_U_After'];
$Phase_3_I_After = $_POST['Phase_3_I_After'];
$Phase_3_P_After = $_POST['Phase_3_P_After'];
$Phase_3_S_After = $_POST['Phase_3_S_After'];
$Phase_3_Q_After = $_POST['Phase_3_Q_After'];
$Phase_3_cos_After = $_POST['Phase_3_cos_After'];
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Did you check the error log?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about *which* variables are being removed and how they're used, rather than how many you removed. I suspect we'll need more information to help here. For starters, what is causing you to think the problem is related to the number of variables? is there an error message?

Comment: @HPierce I tried removing different ones, same behavior.

Comment: @Dekel Edited the question with the error log

Comment: Based on the log it seems like a syntax error. Are you sure this is the exact code you here? What do you have in line 43 in your code?

Comment: Copy + Pasted from the server... line 43 is $Phase_3_Q_Before = $_POST['Phase_3_Q_Before'];

Comment: What is line #42? The errors showing up in your logs indicates an issue on a preceding line of code. One of the 8 POST variables which you are deleting probably have an error so you are literally deleting the error and your code starts working again.

Comment: Solved it, thanks all for the help. it was a dos2unix conversion I was missing after migrating to CentOS from my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you increased the upload sizes?

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Did you check the errors?

```
display_errors = 1
display_startup_errors = 1
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

(add all of these to your php.ini)

Comment: upload_max_filesize and post_max_size were 500M by default.

Comment: display_errors = 1
display_startup_errors = 1
error_reporting = E_ALL 
I've set all 3, it didnt give me more info than before..

Comment: @NadavPeled Than your php.ini is being overrided somewhere else. If you get error 500 that means php is not displaying errors. That may be your problem, because maybe all your modifications in the php.ini are in vain. Run a `phpinfo()` to see what configuration IS loaded.

Comment: phpinfo indicates both display_errors and display_startup_errors are Off, error_reporting is 22527 even when I changed them...
Which is weird, because when I changed max_input_vars it was changed immediately after the restart.

Comment: It may be overrided in either a `.htaccess` file, you `site.conf` file, a `auto_prepend` file, or somewhere earlier in the code. Are you using a CMS? Are you on linux or windows with the apache server?

Comment: I will check those files, im on CentOS

Comment: Solved it, it wasnt your answer but your questions guided me well :) I moved from windows machine to CentOS today, it was a dos2unix conversion I was missing on that php file.